# How to crop features outside an image region using pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, object-detection

We can use ROI-Pool/ROI-Align to crop the sub-features **inside** an image region (which is a rectangle).

I was wondering how to crop features **outside** this region.
In other words, how to set values (of a feature map) **inside** a rectangle region to zero, but values **outside** the region remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this idea of ROI align is quite correct. ROI pool and align are used to take a number of differently sized regions of interest identified in the original input space (i.e. pixel-space) and output a set of same-sized feature crops from the features calculated by (nominally) the convolutional network.

As perhaps a simple answer to your question, though, you simply need to create a mask tensor of ones with the same dimension as your feature maps, and set the values within the ROIs to zero for this mask, then multiply the mask by the feature maps. This will suppress all values within the ROIs. Creation of this mask should be fairly simple. I did it with a for-loop to avoid thinking but there's likely more efficient ways as well.

```
feature_maps                                          # batch_size x num_feature maps x width x height

mask = torch.ones(torch.shape(feature_maps[0,0,:,:]))  
for ROI in ROIs:                                      # assuming each ROI is [xmin ymin xmax ymax]
     mask[ROI[0]:ROI[2],ROI[1]:ROI[3]] = 0

mask = mask.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)                 # 1 x 1 x width x height
mask = mask.repeat(batch_size,num_feature_maps,1,1)   # batch_size x num_feature maps x width x height
output = torch.mul(mask,feature_maps)
```